# Reversing a vector in C++ doesn't work

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a vector in C++. The problem is that when I print out the "reversed" vector, I get the original vector. I know I am missing something. Can I have some tips as to what to think about. I have googled and saw that most people use the same method. The only thing I can think of is that the `inputBinary` vector has a problem with its pointers. When I print out `*begin(inputBinary)` I get `1` but `*end(inputBinary)` gives something like `14743`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<int> convert2Bin(int& n);

int main()
{
    int input;

    cin >> input;
    vector<int> inputBinary = convert2Bin(input);
    reverse(begin(inputBinary), end(inputBinary));
    for(int i = 0; i<inputBinary.size();i++)
    {
        cout << inputBinary[i];    
    }
    return 0;
}


vector<int> convert2Bin(int& n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i = 0, x;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        x = n%2;
        v.push_back(x);
        n = n/2;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: `end` gives you an iterator to one past the end, if you want to see the first and last elements of a vector, use `.front()` and `.back()` respectively

Comment: What is the output?  What do you expect for output?

Comment: Did you try printing out the vector *before* reversing it, to see if the problem is actually reversing it, or something else? Like an incorrect expectation of the result of your `convert2Bin` function?

Comment: I have printed both and get the same value

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're inserting the bits in reverse order while converting from integer to binary. eg. for input 8, `convert2Bin` would look like 0,0,0,1. So, after reversing it would give 1,0,0,0. Also the end() iterator points to the spot just after last element of the vector, so it is no surprise you're getting arbitrary value if you try to print `*end(vec)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> convert2Bin(int& n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i = 0, x;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        x = n%2;
        v.push_back(x);
        n = n/2;
    }
    return v;
}
```

This function already reverse the bits.
When you again apply reverse on vector it make it normal.

Instead of pushing back you can use [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_front/) and push front. After that it will work fine.

Or you can change your function to

```
vector<int> convert2Bin(int& n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i = 0, x;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        x = n%2;
        v.insert(v.begin(),x)
        n = n/2;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed above the problem here is your function that converts decimal to binary. It is giving you the binary representation in reverse order. So after reversing that the binary representation becomes proper and hence you are getting that answer.